# Sum dropdown values on AngularJS 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a page where the user will choose a few drop-downs, each option of each dropdown will have a number value. I want Angular to show the sum of all selected options and store on a variable or something so I can use it on an IF.

Here's the code I used as a workaround:

```
<select id="" [(ngModel)]="select1">
          <option value="1">name1</option>
          <option value="2">name2</option>
</select

<select id="" [(ngModel)]="select2">
          <option value="1">name1</option>
          <option value="2">name2</option>
</select

<b>Points:  </b> {{ select1 -- select2 }}
```

However this does not store in any variable so I cannot use on an IF.

I want to do something like this:

```
<label *ngIf="summ > 16; else error">Higher than 16 </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a function with ngIf where it adds all the model variable values

```
<label *ngIf="calculatesum() > 16"; else error">Higher than 16 </label>
```

and in **`TS`**

```
calculatesum(){
  return select1 + select2 +select3 + select4;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!! It worked like a charm. Just had to change a few things in TS:
calculatesum(){
return parseFloat(this.select1) +parseFloat(this.select2) 
}